# JavaFX CSS: Change TabPane Tab header shape

Tags: java, css, javafx, tabs

I am trying to change the `Tab` header shape in `css`, but when I look at the `css` reference for `JavaFX` in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), I can't find what are the accessible properties of a Tab through `css`. I want to have a trapezoid shape instead of a rectangle. Any idea how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the default [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) in any case:

`Tab`s have the CSS class: `.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab`

So for example adding the following to your CSS file:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
    -fx-background-radius: 20;
}

.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-radius: 20;
}
```

will result in the following:

[image]

For trapezoid you need to use the `-fx-shape` attribute:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab {
      -fx-shape: "M300,290 L310,168 L410,168 L421,290 L300,290 z";
}

.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-shape: "M300,290 L310,168 L410,168 L421,290 L300,290 z";
}
```

which will result in:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know, but it took some time to write an example with an SVGPath:)